# OP edit is identical with my rejected edit

Tags: support, specific-question, review

This is mainly to help me understand how the reviewing of edits (to questions) works. I recently had an [edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/230344) to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426273/how-to-find-the-axis-with-minimum-moment-of-inertia) approved by a reviewer (Chair), but then "rejected by Community" because "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit". Then I discovered that the "subsequent edit" was my edit! All the changes in this edit, including the text explanation of what had been done, were identical, and were actually made by the OP.

I'm not complaining, I'm not that desperate for the editing credit! But I wonder whether the proposed edit is presented to the OP for approval in such a way that he/she believes that the correct course of action is to copy/paste the changes and carry out the edit themselves. Otherwise, how can this event be explained?

I'm also slightly concerned, because I have the impression that SE users who accumulate a lot of "rejected edits" are liable to be penalised in some way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't tell from the timeline, but my guess is that the OP was presented with the edit and chose either "improve this edit" or "reject and edit" by mistake, then applied your changes. Perhaps they will enlighten us.

I can, however, address this concern:

> I'm also slightly concerned, because I have the impression that SE users who accumulate a lot of "rejected edits" are liable to be penalised in some way.

A single rejected edit shouldn't raise any concern about this. I can't remember whether there is any automated restriction on editing privileges or whether it is brought to the attention of the moderators by a (perhaps automatic) flag. But if you were to discover you had an account restriction because you were making good edit suggestions and other people were applying them on your behalf, I think we would work with you and the team to fix the problem rather than somehow punish you arbitrarily.

Comment: If I understand correctly, "Improve this edit" automatically accepts the edit suggestion, but "Reject and edit" takes you to the editing prompt based on the *old* version. I've [occasionally](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/229112) clicked "Improve this edit", copied the text, and gone back to "Reject and edit" in order to build on the edit suggestion while still rejecting, to send a specific message (which I then detail in the editing comments!), and my impression is that the combination here requires something that elaborate to explain.

Comment: I would think that they didn't select reject and edit: that would show up in the review history for the edit. And the author of the question doesn't have anything in his review history on his profile. It's more likely that as a confused new user, he had an edit page open already, saw the suggested edit on a separate tab, copied the content into his existing edit, and then submitted that edit. That would explain the Community user's rejection message too.